# Raspberry Pi HDMI not Working

Tags: hdmi, noobs, pi-3, config.txt

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 & a Windows 10 PC. I have extracted the NOOBS file and saved the extracted file on an SD Card. I tried to do the first boot on my Raspberry Pi with the SD Card inserted and also the HDMI cable and Keyboard & Mouse inserted into the USB of the Raspi. Unfortunately my display doesn't seem to show anything and is blank. I know for certain that the HDMI cable & my display works perfectly since they work with my PC. I read on a couple of forums that I must add the following line 'hdmi_force_hotplug=1' to the config.txt file in the NOOBS folder on the SD card. But I cannot seem to find the config.txt file. Below is the screenshot of how my noobs folder looks like.

[image: Noobs folder]

Comment: You should edit any extra information into your post, not as an answer. I don't know where you read about config.txt, but this is for Raspbian. I can't help with NOOBS - few, if any, of the experienced users on this site use NOOBS, but directly install Raspbian.

Answer (score 1):

## Directly install Raspbian

Because I couldn't use the NOOBs setup either, I strongly recommend you try to install the image of your favourite operating system directly on the sd card.

---

**Useful links:**

Raspbian img file:
http://www.chip.de/downloads/Raspbian-Jessie-fuer-Raspberry-Pi_56691903.html

Img installer:
http://www.chip.de/downloads/Win32-Disk-Imager_46121030.html

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you didn't install any OS to your RPi yet.

I see you extracted files under `F:\NOOBS_v1_9_0`, but files must be at root, check [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/noobs-setup/) for detailed introduction.

btw: `config.txt` and `hdmi_force_hotplug=1` for already installed Raspbians